# NPM peerDependencies how to specify major version range

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

### Case

I'm developing a common react component for 2 our projects which uses 2 different version of react-bootstrap.

```
First one: "react-bootstrap": "^0.33.1"
Second one: "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16"
```

In library's packages json I have:

```json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.33.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0"
  }
}
```

The component works fine with both (used API remains the same between these 2 versions).

### The problem

When I'm trying to install that dependency in second project I get next error:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-bootstrap@"^0.33.1" from @company/lib@1.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@company/lib
npm ERR!   @company/lib@"1.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

### The question is

How can I specify in `peerDependencies` that lib can be used in both, 0.33.1 and 1.0.0 versions? Without forcing `npm i` to ignore these errors using `--force` flag.

Answer (score 4):

So, it supports OR operator
`"react-bootstrap": "^0.33.1 || ^1.0.0-beta.16"`

but it doesn't solve the problem 'cause the package is building using old version.

So the solution was in just:

1. Write 2 scripts that patch package.json with correct version in peerDeeps and change package name (from `@company/package` to `@company/package-legacy`)
2. Update CI/CD pipeline to build both versions of package

Not so clean, but works perfect.